# Diffusion of particles across a plane surface

Tags: physical-chemistry, concentration, diffusion

> A relatively viscous material is coated with a thin film consisting of gold nanoparticles that can diffuse into the material. We can assume that all particles have a diameter of $\pu{25 nm}.$ Coating can be seen as a completely flat surface.
>
> In an experiment performed at $\pu{30 °C},$ the nanoparticle concentration $c$ was determined at different distances $d$ from the coating after 60 days. The following data were obtained:
> $$
> \begin{array}{rr}
> \hline
> d/\pu{mm} & c/\pu{mol dm^-3} \\
> \hline
> 1 & \pu{8.7E-12} \\
> 2 & \pu{5.8E-12} \\
> 4 & \pu{1.1E-12} \\
> 6 & \pu{7.5E-14} \\
> 8 & \pu{1.7E-15} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> In the same viscous material, equal number of latex nanoparticles with radii of $5$ and $\pu{10 nm}$ are added. How far from the point source do we have to go for the ratio (in concentration) between the small and the large latex particles to be $2$ or higher after $1,$ $10$ and $100$ days, respectively? The temperature is the same as in the first attempt.

I began by plotting $\ln c$ against $x^2$ to determine the diffusivity constant $D$ using the equation

$$c = \frac{n_0}{A\sqrt{\pi Dt}}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{4Dt}\right).$$

From this I got that the slope $-0.135$ and $D = \pu{3.57E-7}.$

However, I am unsure how to continue. At first I thought that I could use the same equation by finding the ratio $c(\pu{5 nm})/c(\pu{10 nm})$ and then solving for $x$ since both $A$ and $n_0$ would cancel out as they are equal.

But I think that there should be some other way in which I use *both* the radii and the temperature given as I don't see any other reason as to why they are provided.

Comment: @Maurice Please try to accomplish *complete* edits. Adding a single backslash and changing two braces to curly brackets when there are numerous other issues *should not* be the point of an edit. Keep in mind the post is bumped each time it gets edited, and such minuscular edits become annoying quickly.

Comment: You could try using the Stokes_Einstein law $D=k_BT/(6\pi\eta r)$ where $\eta$ is viscosity, $r$ radius. You have $D$ and $r$ from your data so you know how these are related, i.e. you know $k_BT/(6\pi\eta)$.

Comment: The average distance diffused is $\sqrt{4Dt}$ in two dimensions and this could also be useful.

Comment: @porphyrin I don't quite understand how using Stokes-Einstein's law would benefit me here, what exactly do I want from that equation? I would think that I somehow want to include the concentration ratio in order to solve the problem